# Roll to another case in PHP switch

Tags: php, switch-statement

For example I have this:

```
switch ($action)
{
    case 'my_action':
        doSomething();
    break;

    case 'second_action':
        if ($this_is_true)
        {
            $action = 'my_action';
        }
        else
        {
            doSomethingElse();
        }
    break;
}
```

Is the example above going to go through the switch again and then call the first case `my_action` if the second case `second_action` has `$this_is_true` variable set to true?

If this doesn't work, what would be an alternative?

Comment: Does this have to be solved with a switch. Why not use if:

if($action == 'my_action' || $this_is_true){ doSomething(); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
switch ($action)
{
case 'my_action':
case 'second_action':
    if ($this_is_true || $action=='my_action')
    {
       doSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
break;
}
```

When $action is equal to `'my_action'` it will run through the `case`, as it finds no `break` sentence then it will run through the second case until it finds the `break` sentence.

Please give a look to example #3 in http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php to find out more about no breaking switch cases.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't.  Just call `doSomething();` in the 'second_action' case.

I wouldn't use a switch in this simple case, but if it is very long then maybe:

```
$do = false;

switch ($action)
{
    case 'my_action':
        $do = true;
    break;

    case 'second_action':
        if ($this_is_true)
        {
            $action = 'my_action';
            $do = true;
        }
        else
        {
            doSomethingElse();
        }
    break;
}

if($do) { doSomething(); }
```

Comment: Well, in my case `doSomething()` is a VERY long block of code, which would cause a huge code repetition.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it this way:

```
do {
    switch ($action)
    {
        case 'my_action':
            $this_is_true = false;
            doSomething();
        break;

        case 'second_action':
            if ($this_is_true)
            {
                $action = 'my_action';
            }
            else
            {
                doSomethingElse();
            }
        break;
    }
} while($this_is_true);
```

Do not forget to switch `$this_is_true` to `false` where it needed!
But this code is not beautiful... May be you better to refactor your code.